# I don't need clickable label of my checkboxes

Tags: checkbox, click, label

I added a custom checkbox in my form but when I click on the checkbox label then wy my checkbox done checked? I don't want label clickable

Comment: can we done this through JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the checkmark to be clickable then use two views one textview to present the label and one checkbox without text.

Comment: I assumed that this question was Android related, is that the case?

Comment: No! Its for all browsers and devices

Comment: But i fixed that it was in contact form 7 and input field was in label tag that's why label was clickable i was exclude input field from label tag.